# angular validate that a pair of form fields are empty or both are filled

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, validation

I have created a student form that has 4 to 5 fields. For the contact number, I have 2 fields, country code and phone number. I want to throw an error if the user only inputs one of the two fields ie country code is entered but the phone number isn't or vice-versa. However, if both fields are left empty, then it's valid as both are non-mandatory fields. I don't know how I can achieve this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here is my template:

```
<mat-form-field >
<input matInput type="number"   formControlName="countryCode" placeholder="Country Code(+)" name="countryCode" class="form-control" id="countryCode">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field >
<input matInput type="number" formControlName="phnNumber" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phnNumber" class="form-control" id="phnNumber">
</mat-form-field>
```

My Form group:

```
this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      studentName: ['', Validators.required],
      phnNumber: new FormControl(''),
      countryCode: new FormControl(''),
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom validator which you place on the `FormGroup` as a whole rather than the individual controls. Your call to `FormBuilder` becomes:

```js
this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({

      studentName: ['', Validators.required],
      phnNumber: new FormControl(''),
      countryCode: new FormControl(''),
    }, { validators: myFormValidator });
```

And you create a Validator (either in the same file or elsewhere and export):

```js
export const myFormValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
  const phnNumber = control.get('phnNumber').value;
  const countryCode = control.get('countryCode').value;

  if (phnNumber && !countryCode || countryCode && !phnNumber) {
    return { 'phoneNumberError': true };
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

That way the custom Validator grabs what it needs from the whole group as opposed to needing to validate controls individually.

Comment: this wont work as expected since you need to compare the values of the controls, not if the controls exist

Comment: Edited to extract values, thanks for catching that!

Comment: This is what I would have suggested also, I up-voted it. My only issue with this style is the magic strings to get the controls out of the form group (not sure there is a better way), but that is life. I would also name the control as formGroup. I WOULD ALSO suggest you put these 2 controls in their own formgroup

Comment: Yep this one is great

Comment: I'm getting error No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'myFormValidator'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.

Comment: Have you put the validator somewhere accessible? Either in the same class (and accessed with `this.myFormValidator` or elsewhere and exported/imported?

Comment: @Maccurt yeah I'm not sure if there's a better way than the `get` calls. I just followed the docs format for this one, including labelling the group as `control`. Perhaps `formGroup` is better semantically. And yeah I thought about suggesting placing the controls in a separate group, I agree it's a better pattern

Comment: Oh I forgot to do that.

Comment: I tried this.However I am not getting any error on the form fields.I've added this to template <mat error*ngIf="addForm.hasError('phoneNumberError')">Password Mismatch!</mat-error>

Comment: The fields themselves won't show an error, just the form as a whole.

Comment: I wanted to show the errors on the field so that the user knows what to fill

Comment: OK I hadn't seen your snippet. This function should still throw the error properly, although it's hard to figure out from here what's going on. Play around with the logic a bit if need be, because as far as I can tell, this should work (I've implemented similar things in many other forms without issue).

Comment: Even if i try to submit with one of the pair empty,I'm able to create a new student.Do I need to add something in the template code as well?

Comment: You could always add explicit empty-string checks. I don't see why it should need them, but hey…is your Submit button disabled if the form is invalid?

Comment: No the submit button is not disabled.If submit is clicked with wrong inputs errors are shown

Comment: OK. Either way, this is the pattern for validating across multiple controls. Try debugging the validator, but something very close to this should work.

Comment: I don't know about your specific setup, and I haven't played around with overriding Material's built-in behavior, I'm afraid.